# How to configure to send airflow task logs to datadog?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, datadog

I deployed airflow with helm in Kubernetes

```
helm upgrade --install datadog-monitoring \
    --set datadog.apiKey="xxx" \
    --set clusterAgent.enabled=true \
    --set clusterAgent.token="xxx" \
    --set datadog.criSocketPath=null \
    --set datadog.logs.enabled=true \
    --set datadog.logs.containerCollectAll=true \
    --set datadog.containerExcludeLogs="name:dashboard-metrics-scraper name:kubernetes-dashboard" \
    --set datadog.dogstatsd.port=8125 \
    --set datadog.dogstatsd.useHostPort=true \
    --set datadog.dogstatsd.nonLocalTraffic=true \
    --set datadog.apm.portEnabled=true \
    --set datadog.apm.port=8126 \
    datadog/datadog
```

All other configuration files are default ones.

I can see some logs in datadog

```
[2023-04-29 11:51:26,584: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[2a8bbfc1-4c3c-4123-bdc8-36dc6fe7799d] succeeded in 59.32762966118753s: None
```

However the task logs is not sent to datadog, I can see `/opt/airflow/logs` does have a lot of task logs but they are never sent to datadog, what is the right way to do that?

It seems only stdout logs are uploaded to datadog, what is missing here to upload task logs to datadog?

Comment: You need to configure airflow to connect to dogstatsd https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/?tab=host#configure-datadog-agent-airflow-integration